# why this link redirects to mob.org?

Tags: redirect, blogger

I don't know why this link "http://am.get4mobile.net/android/lRb7KNbLPeIZ72mhPlEITw/1451532270/bubble_shooter_treasure_pop/1_bubble_shooter_treasure_pop.apk" 
redirects to site mob.org when i keep it in my blogger. I really need the solution so it doesn't redirect to mob.org any one to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

this problem not from your blog or from blogger or anything like that

the problem is that the site's (play.mob.org) system redirecting you to the post\link that you downloaded the game\app from or you trying to download the game\app from

you can download it and reupload it on any uploading site like mediafire

you can't prevent redirecting

Comment: I know But don't we have some script to get rid from that redirect ?

Comment: No we Have i have Once visited one of site i just cant remember which site that site got one script from which we can get rid of that redirect .... but i just cant figure it out so i asked here if anyone got that script .. but alright no one got ... Anyway thanks for the Help :) '+1'